How To Use Call Log API in RingCentral
I am new to ring central and fairly inexperienced with API's, how can I use an API from RingCentral to pull call data into Power BI?
I've not tried anything, only looked at different potential options like using data factory (Not Optimal) or using an app like Tray.io to accomplish this.
